# KineticJS Reclaiming Memory

Tags: ios, kineticjs

I have been using KineticJS to build an iOS app (UIWebView). I created a simple example app just to get an understand of memory utilization. I create a single stage, added 100 layers to it and one line to each layer. The amount of memory allocated for the stage and layers was about 6 Mb per layer or 600 Mb. I then added code to remove each layer in a setInterval function and then called stage.reset() just to be sure. In profiling, the memory utilization did not reduce.

I reviewed my code to be sure I wasn't keeping references to the layers. In one test I also dereferenced the stage but the memory allocated value does not change. Could this be a bug or is there some other means to reclaim memory using KineticJS?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. @Ryan, did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Jaffer This wasn't my question; I merely added a tag to it. Best of luck!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that @Ryan. Bruce, I shifted to Fabric.js and the memory footprint of my page improved significantly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'garbage collection' problem for many browsers. Basically, just dereferencing won't free up the memory. You have to rely on the browser to recognize when to free up some memory. I had the same problem on with some Android browsers. Basically, I just installed the latest Firefox browser and it worked a lot better. 
Sorry I couldn't be more help.